# Immutable.js Push into array in nested object

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Assume there is an object:

```
const object = {
  'foo': {
    'bar': [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

I need to push `4` to `object.foo.bar` array.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS(object)
const newState = initialState.setIn(
  ['foo', 'bar', object.foo.bar.length],
  4
)
console.log(newState.toJS())
```

But I don't really like it, since I need to use `object.foo.bar.length` in the path. In my real example object is nested much deeper, and getting array's length looks very ugly. Is there another, more convenient way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should work

```
initialState.updateIn(['foo', 'bar'], arr => arr.push(4))
```

References:

- https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/updateIn

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: [arr.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is wrong, as it returns the /length/ of the new array.  This will result in {foo: { bar: 3}}.  You want to use [arr.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: `arr.push` is correct here but the naming is a little misleading: `arr` in his example is Immutable's List because OP created the state through `Immutable.fromJS`. `List.push` returns a new list with the argument(s) appended, so this does exactly what OP asked.

Comment: @PabloCG you're wrong, `push` here is not a `Array.prototype` method, but an immutablejs `List` method, which **DOES NOT** modify the original object.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `seamless-immutable`, when I'm adding a new item to array of nested object, I got this error:

> The push method cannot be invoked on an Immutable data structure.

My array still has `push` method, but it doesn't work. The solution is use concat instead, more details on [#43](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/issues/43):

```
initialState.updateIn(['foo', 'bar'], arr => arr.concat([4]));
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Same issue here, makes sense since push modifies which isn't possible with immutable data structures.