# Redux reducer with Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, immutable.js

I want to add a post to an array of posts in the reducer.
Normally I would just do this:

```
CREATE_NEW__POST_SUCCESS: {
    return {
        ...state,
        fetchingPosts: false,
        error: null,
        posts: [...state.posts, ...action.payload],
        };
```

However my current project requires me to use Immutable.js
With Immutable the state is set with .set() or .merge() or .update()

```
case CREATE_NEW_POST_SUCCESS: {
    return state
        .set('fetchingPosts', false)
        .set('posts', action.payload)
        .set('postsError', null);
```

This overwrites the whole array of posts with just one post object.
I tried lots of things like

```
 .set('posts' ,[...state.posts, ...action.payload])
```

But no joy

Comment: Have toy tried doing this `.set('posts', [...state.posts, ...action.payload])`? Or using the `merge` method to add to the posts?

Comment: yes i tried that, Not sure what Im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can use `updateIn` similarly to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610179/immutable-js-push-into-array-in-nested-object).

```
case CREATE_NEW_POST_SUCCESS: {
    return state
        .set('fetchingPosts', false)
        .updateIn(['posts'], posts => posts.push(action.payload))
        .set('postsError', null);
```

Comment: this looks perfect, thank you. Still can't get it to work for some reason.I'll keep looking around for what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think `state.merge()` and `concat()` could work here:

```js
case CREATE_NEW_POST_SUCCESS: {
    return state.merge({
        fetchingPosts: false,
        posts: state.get('posts').concat(action.payload),
        postError: null,
    })
}
```